# How to profile my APIs for concurrent requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, postman, profiler

## Scenario

Hi, I have a collection of APIs that I run on *Postman* using `POST` requests. The `flask` and `redis` servers are set up using `docker.`

## What I'm trying to do

I need to profile my setup/APIs in a high traffic environment. So,

1. I need to create concurrent requests calling these APIs
2. The profiling aims to get the system conditions with respect to memory (total memory consumed by the application), time (total execution time taken to create and execute the requests) and CPU-time (or the percentage of CPU consumption)

## What I have tried

I am familiar with some memory profilers like `mprof` and time profiler like `line_profiler`. But I could not get a profiler for the CPU consumption. I have run the above two profilers (`mprof` and `line_profiler`) on a single execution to get the line-by-line profiling results for my code. But this focuses on the function wise results.I have also created parallel requests earlier using `asyncio`,etc but that was for some **simple** API-like programs without `POSTMAN`. My current APIs work with a lot of data in the `body` section of `POSTMAN`

## Where did I get stuck

With docker, this problem gets trickier for me.

1. Firstly, I am unable to get concurrent requests
2. I do not know how to profile my APIs when using POSTMAN (perhaps there is an option to do it without `POSTMAN`) with respect to the three parameters: time, memory and CPU consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've been using the embbed flask server(dev server) that is NOT production ready and,by default, it supports only on request per time. For concurrent requests should be looking to use gunicorn or some other wsgi server like uWsgi.

Postman is only a client of your API, i don't see it's importance here. If you want to do a stress test or somethin like that, you can write your own script or use known tools, like jmetter.

Hope it helps!